# Prevent duplicate of multiple constraint sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

Suppose I have a table :

```
Table A:

Id Name     Movie   Comment 

1  Foo     Bar  anything
2  Foo     Bar  anything
```

Here I want to make sure that the user cannot insert Foo and Bar twice , but he is allowed to insert Foo , foobar .
One solution to prevent this duplication was to add this statement `ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY(Name , Movie).` That was probably for sql not sqlite. I wrote the same command in python for sqlite3 as `cur.execute("ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE KEY(Name,Movie)")`. It gave me the error sqlite3.operationalerror: near "unique" syntax error. Is there anything that can be done while creating the table A , or is there any mistake in my sqlite query .

Help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_Movies ON table(Name, Movie)
```

This is standard SQL, and documented at http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html.  (SQLite's on-line documentation is pretty comprehensive)